# Return vector (fixed-length array) from prime-sieve function and convert it to list later

Tags: scheme

I found a `prime-sieve` function which uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate the first `n` primes. The method is based on Donald Knuth's algorithm and I copied it from [here](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sieve-of-eratosthenes):

```
; http://community.schemewiki.org/?sieve-of-eratosthenes
(define (prime-sieve n) 
  (let ((pvector (make-vector (+ 1 n) #t))) ; if slot k then 2k+1 is a prime 
    (let loop ((p 3) ; Maintains invariant p = 2j + 1 
               (q 4) ; Maintains invariant q = 2j + 2jj 
               (j 1) 
               (k '()) 
               (vec pvector)) 
      (letrec ((lp (lambda (p q j k vec) 
                     (loop (+ 2 p) 
                           (+ q (- (* 2 (+ 2 p)) 2)) 
                           (+ 1 j) 
                           k 
                           vec))) 
               (eradicate (lambda (q p vec) 
                            (if (<= q n) 
                                (begin (vector-set! vec q #f) 
                                       (eradicate (+ q p) p vec)) 
                                vec)))) 
        (if (<= j n) 
            (if (eq? #t (vector-ref vec j)) 
                (begin (lp p q j q (eradicate q p vec))) 
                (lp p q j k vec)) 
            #t)))))
```

I want to use that function to return a vector which can be converted to a list with the function `sieve-to-list`:

```
(define (sieve-to-list s upperlimit)
  (let aux ((i 2) (acc '()))
    (if (> i upperlimit)
        (reverse acc)
        (if (= (vector-ref s i) 1)
            (aux (add1 i) (cons i acc))
            (aux (add1 i) acc)))))
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure if the first function returns a vector since `(vector? (prime-sieve 1000))` returns #f. And when I run the below code and try to see a list of the first 1000 primes:

```
(sieve-to-list (prime-sieve 1000) 1000)
```

I get the error:

> vector-ref: contract violation
> expected: vector?
> given: #t
> argument position: 1st
> other arguments...:

If I change the #t in `prime-sieve` to something else that is displayed after "given".

I don't know much about vectors. If the sieve does not return a vector, why doesn't it and how can I make it return a vector? And if it does return a vector, why doesn't my conversion function not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you linked to *prints* the prime numbers, but does not store them or return them in any way. To store them, you should use the accumulator technique like you have in `sieve-to-list`. Anyway, here's a fixed version (I took the opportunity to clean the code up a lot, too):

```
(define (prime-sieve n)
  (define vec (make-vector (+ n 1) #t))
  (let loop ((p 3) ; Maintains invariant p = 2j + 1
             (q 4) ; Maintains invariant q = 2j + 2jj
             (j 1)
             (result '(2)))
    (define (lp result)
      (loop (+ p 2)
            (+ q p p 2)
            (+ j 1)
            result))
    (define (eradicate!)
      (do ((q q (+ q p)))
          ((> q n))
        (vector-set! vec q #f)))

    (cond ((> j n) (reverse result))
          ((vector-ref vec j) (eradicate!)
                              (lp (cons p result)))
          (else (lp result)))))
```

This returns a list, not a vector. That's because the results are built incrementally, which lists are good for and vectors are not.

I validated the above code by comparing the results against [my implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75058/216).

---

Do you use Racket? I noticed you used `add1` in your code. If so, here's the same algorithm, but using `for` comprehensions in Racket, which is more concise and easy to read:

```
(define (prime-sieve n)
  (define vec (make-vector (add1 n) #t))
  (define (eradicate! p q)
    (do ((q q (+ q p)))
        ((> q n))
      (vector-set! vec q #f)))
  (cons 2 (for/list ((j (in-range 1 (add1 n)))
                     #:when (vector-ref vec j))
            (define p (+ j j 1))
            (eradicate! p (* 2 j (add1 j)))
            p)))
```

In this version, `p` and `q` are calculated afresh from `j` each time rather than be accumulated, but I don't think that's a huge problem.

Comment: I use `#lang scheme`. Thanks for your answer. This makes it way more readable. :) You say that it is better to generate a list than a vector in this case, but since I have to look up the primes in the sieve about a million more times than I have to generate the list (only once) it is necessary to have an array/vector returned. The lookup in a list is too slow. Is it possible to return a vector instead of a list?

Comment: Just using `list->vector` on the list is fast enough. :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: And note that your sieve misses the prime 2.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Glad you like. Yep, use `list->vector` to convert to vector afterwards (better to do it yourself than make the original functions do it). [*My* sieve implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75058/216) (linked in my answer) does put in a 2, but the Community Scheme Wiki one (that you copied, and that I adapted for this answer, mostly to show you how I would refactor it) doesn't, so I edited it to put in the 2 there too. :-)

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers As for needing to have fast lookups, are you using a binary search on the vector? If so, and if you're using Racket, consider using Racket's sets (you can use `list->set`, or, since we're holding numbers only, `list->seteqv` is faster). There are mutable sets (based on hashtables) and immutable sets (based on AVL trees), so choose whichever type you prefer based on the performance characteristics (and ordering, if needed) you like.

Comment: It also seems that the `n` has another meaning than expected. It returns primes up to roughly half of n.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers If you're talking about the `prime-sieve` in this post, it returns all primes below 2n. It does **not** return n prime numbers; there is no efficient method for doing that (at least, not based on Sieve of Eratosthenes). Even [my implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75058/216) is named `primes-up-to-about` for a reason: the n specifies an upper limit of the search, not the number of primes.

Comment: In other words, assuming a hypothetical SQL table named `primes`, you can query for `SELECT val FROM primes WHERE val < n`, but you cannot query for `SELECT val FROM primes LIMIT n`. :-)

Comment: But! If you know a priori the number of primes you want, you can use https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/ to look up what the nth prime is, and then use _that_ as an upper bound for the function here. :-) (Hint: the function here uses a _lot_ of memory if you're doing a big search. [My implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75058/216) is more space-efficient, since it uses a bitset instead of a vector (i.e., uses one bit per odd number, rather than one pointer per odd number).)